# How can a put a static picture over Google Dynamic Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have added a Google Maps Javascript API (dynamic map) to my web-site. I want to put a static picture in the bottom left corner over the maps div - something like a legend. It will not move when the user scrows around.

Is there a way to do it through Google Javascript API or shall I just add a div, put it over the map with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to add this sort of thing using the Google Maps Javascript API. It is considered a Custom Control, and here is a [link to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls). You would do that if you need to have your element move around when screen real estate gets tight and you want Google Maps to take care of it.

If you aren't concerned with reflowing the other controls as the map appears on screens of various sizes, you can just go with an absolutely positioned element. If you don't want your overlay to affect the map ui by capturing mouse events, just set `pointer-events:none;` on that element.